# The specifics of casting to int, from double and long

Tags: java, casting, integer, double, long-integer

Hi so i recently saw a question structured much like this

```
int a= (int) Math.pow(2,32);
System.out.println(a); //prints out Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

After i answered the question it turns out i got it wrong, i answered Integer.MIN_VALUE but the correct answer was Integer.MAX_VALUE. After further testing i realized any double that i cast to an int that is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE just makes the int equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE.
For Example

```
int a = (int) ((double) Integer.MAX_VALUE+100);
System.out.println(a); //prints out Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

After further testing i realized if you try to cast a long to an int, it seems to assign the int to a seemingly random number.

So my question is. What the heck is going on, why does the double value not overflow the integer when you cast it to an int? and why does casting a long to an int return a seemingly random number

Comment: It's not a random number. It's the rightmost 32 bits of the long.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the double cast contains code like `if( int_val > Integer.MAX_VALUE ) { return Integer.MAX_VALUE; }` except in C of course.  Have you tried looking at the source code in the Open JDK project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of these conversions is part of the Java language specification, [Item 5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).

You can see there, that when converting from long to int, most significant bits are discarded, leaving the least significant 32 bits.

And also, that if the result of rounding a `double` or `float` is a number that is too small or too large to represent as an `int` (or `long`), the minimal or maximal representable number will be chosen.

There is no way for us here to answer "why" for a decision that has been made long ago. But this is the way the language is defined, and you can rely on it being the same in any Java environment you work in.

Answer (score 0):

for casting a double value to integer it would erase the after point value and the the remainder is like rounding down the value of the double 
and for the first question the int would return the value it could save in 8 bites so it would seem to be the min.value 
long a=  Math.pow(2,32); would give you the max.value 
and for casting long to an integer It's not a random number. It's the rightmost 32 bits of the long number 
sorry for my bad writing 
english is my second language